# Get own pyproject.toml dependencies programatically

Tags: python, python-packaging

I use a `pyproject.toml` file to list a package's dependencies:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "foobar"
version = "1.0"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
dependencies = [
  "requests>=2.0",
  "numpy",
  "tomli;python_version<'3.11'",
]
```

Is is possible, from within the package, to get the list of its own dependencies as strings? In the above case, it should give

```py
["requests", "numpy"]
```

if used with Python>=3.11, and

```py
["requests", "numpy", "tomli"]
```

otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```py
import importlib.metadata
import packaging.requirements

def _get_dependencies(name):
    rd = metadata(name).get_all('Requires-Dist')
    deps = []
    for req in rd:
        req = packaging.requirements.Requirement(req)
        if req.marker is not None and not req.marker.evaluate():
            continue
        deps.append(req.name)
    return deps
```

***References***:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-metadata
- https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#importlib_metadata.metadata
- https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/requirements.html

Comment: This doesn't strip the version requirements, e.g., `"requests>=2.0"` still has `>=2.0`.

Comment: You can use [*`packaging`*](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) to parse these values and get the part you want to keep.